# Need help with using Saxon-B(version 9.1.0.8) with Java 1.4.2

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I need to transform one XML document into another using XSLT (for now from command line).  I have to use Java 1.4.2.  Based on that someone recommended using Saxon and provided the XSLT.  It seems simple it should work, but I am lost.
  I come more form a .NET environment, and have worked with XML and XSLT but not with Saxon and I am not that strong in Java.

Let me start by explaining what my problem is and what I have tried so far:
The Error:

`C:\Projects\new_saxon_download>java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:source.xml -xsl:style.xsl -o:output.xml

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/ext/DefaultHandler2`

```
        at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.(Configuration.java:2047)
        at net.sf.saxon.Transform.setFactoryConfiguration(Transform.java:81)
        at net.sf.saxon.Transform.doTransform(Transform.java:133)
        at net.sf.saxon.Transform.main(Transform.java:66)
```

Steps that led me here:

1. I downloaded Saxon-B by following a link from this [page](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.3HE)
2. I also found some information on a dependency about SAX2 from this
   [page](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2028025&group_id=29872&atid=397617) and thus obtained that as well.
3. Set the CLASSPATH in my session:

    `set CLASSPATH=.;C:\Projects\new_saxon_download\saxon9.jar;C:\Projects\new_saxon_download\sax2r2.jar`
4. Tried the transformation:

     `java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:source.xml -xsl:style.xsl -o:output.xml`

Then I get the error shown above.  I have tried multiple google search, but nothing has helped.

Any advice or solution would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-cp` to your java command line? (`java -cp %CLASSPATH% net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:source.xml -xsl:style.xsl -o:output.xml`)

Comment: @DevNull Tried your suggestion, but still the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GOT IT - the description on how to fix the dependendcy issue is crap (sorry).

This file `sax2r2.jar` isn't the one you have to add to the classpath. It contains another jar (`sax.jar`) and that's the library you actually need. Just extract the sax2r2.jar and put `sax.jar` on the classpath, then it should work.

---

Give this a try: apache xml-commons includes `xml-api.jar`. I can't tell if this is usable with java 1.4.12 but it's worth a try.

[Binary releases can be found here](http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/ftp.apache.org/dist//xerces/xml-commons/). Download one of the xml-commons-external archives, extract xml-api.jar and add that to your classpath.

Comment: Do you know the right location for sax.jar that works correctly with this version?  I don't have that file.

Comment: As I said, it's **inside** the `sax2r2.jar`. A *jar* is a simple zip archive, just extract (unzip) and you'll find it!

Comment: Andreas_D - Is this just an issue with the java version? I don't have any dependency issues when using saxon9.

Comment: Nevermind. I see in the OP's link to http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2028025&group_id=29872&atid=397617 that it is related to the java version.

Comment: @Andreas_D Did the extract, changed the classpath, but still get the error. (FYI - for someone like me who does not know much java, you need jar.exe to do the extract)

Comment: Additionally based on the last comment on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2028025&group_id=29872&atid=397617) this issue was not fixed with that file.

Comment: @Andreas In comment xml-commons did you mean to write "xml-apis.jar" instead of "xml-api.jar"